# Apps stay in background even after turning the phone off

Tags: 7.0-nougat, shutdown

I generally see this in all the Android phones I ever had. I have certain apps in the background and then turn off the phone. If I turn it on again the next day these apps seem to still be in the background. It could be any app, Google Maps, Candy Crash etc.

Why does this happen? Don't Android phones turn off completely? Do these app really stay in the background?

Comment: @IrfanLatif No no I am talking about every app. It could be Candy Crash, Google Maps or Spendee. Or all of them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behavior of Android from Lollipop onwards. See [this blog](https://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/17/lollipop-feature-spotlight-the-recent-apps-list-now-persists-through-reboot/) which talks of that ( Recents (or Overview)). It is only a *list* of apps that you used is shown and it *doesn't* mean that these are running after reboot, so it shouldn't be a concern (unless you want to hide some app or web page that you visited). You can check running apps from settings and you would see that these are fewer than what you see in the overview

Only on earlier versions they would be cleared on reboot

Comment: I more question. How can I see the running apps from settings?

Comment: On Oreo you can see from the developer options 9Tap build number  7 times to reveal). On earlier ones I don't recollect but you can search in the settings using the search function